# Python - Find string between variable number of substrings

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, substring

I have a string which is 
`[-0.0597212   0.00344087 -0.23413301  0.02406648]`

As you see, there is `[` at first, there are 3 spaces between 1st and 2nd value, 1 space between 2nd and 3rd value, 2 spaces between 3rd and 4th value, and there is `]` at the end.

I want to decompose these 4 numerical values with their signs and I will assign these 4 values to an 4-element array.

For example;

```
a[0]=-0.0597212
a[1]=0.00344087
a[2]=-0.23413301
a[3]=0.02406648
```

Normally there will be 128 elements with like this text (there will be maximum 3 spaces, minimum 1 space between values), but I want to try to find the solution with this example. I tried `split.strip()` and `replace()` functions but I didn't find any solution for me. Can you help me ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're working with a string representation of a numpy array, rather than an actual numpy array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a="[-0.0597212   0.00344087 -0.23413301  0.02406648]"

#split string
a = a.split() 

#delete open & close square bracket
a[0] =  a[0][1:] 
a[-1] = a[-1][:-1] 

#convert to float
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] = float(a[i])
```

Comment: so much thanks, I tried with 128 elements and it worked !! but the only bug is, if it ends like "0.0192611 ]" (1 space before "]" ), it shows whole numbers but with an error "ValueError: could not convert string to float:", so do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Welcome dude :D For that case you can just add this code before convert to float:
if a[-1]=='':
    a.pop(-1)

Comment: special thanks for answer dude, it works perfectly :) but I wondered the logic on a[0] and a[-1] line. Can you briefly explain this?

Comment: given variable a is list on python, a[0] mean the first value of list and a[-1] mean last value of the list, that's how Python work. a[0] =  a[0][1:]  changing the value of a[0] with substring of previous value from index 1 until last index (a[0] still a string and Python start index from 0). You can learn more (or maybe just find what you need) on this book: https://www.souravsengupta.com/cds2015/python/LPTHW.pdf

Answer (score 2):

```
list(map(float, txt[1:-1].split()))
```

Comment: This just assumes that the first and last character should be removed, what if there is something around them, e.g. `     [ 1 2 3   ]       `?

Comment: @zvone I made the liberty of making the assumption based on the question asked.  It is very specifically mentioned about the first and last characters in the string.

Comment: thank you mujjiga but I didn't understand how can I print the whole elements of array?

Comment: You mean a = list(map(float, txt[1:-1].split())); print (a)

Comment: also if you have spaces around [ and ] you can use a = list(map(float, txt.strip()[1:-1].split()));print (a)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `numpy()`:

```
import numpy as np

s = '[-0.0597212   0.00344087 -0.23413301  0.02406648]'

np.fromstring(s.strip('[]'), dtype=float, sep=' ')
# [-0.0597212   0.00344087 -0.23413301  0.02406648]
```

You can also use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
import re

ast.literal_eval(re.sub(r'\s+', ',', s))
# [-0.0597212, 0.00344087, -0.23413301, 0.02406648]
```

Comment: thank you Mykola Zotko but I didn't understand how can I print the whole elements of array?